# Local json file to fill "allowed values" option in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I have a list of options in json format residing within Rundeck's server which I would like to use for filling out the "Allowed values" parameter in a new option.
The documentation states: "It must be accessible via HTTP(S) or on the local disk for the Rundeck server.", but sticking the path of the file fails the option generation and I could not see any example of it.

Would someone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `file:\` to access the file locally (at "Allowed values"), take a look at this example:

`video.json` file:

```json
[
 {"name":"youtube", "value":"youtube.com"},
 {"name":"twitch", "value":"twitch.tv"}
]
```

job definition file ([here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions) how to import to your Rundeck instance for testing):

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option enforcedvalues='true' name='video_service' valuesUrl='file:/path/to/video.json' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>4be0ef08-889a-4366-ba29-0b0302fb5391</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>AllowedValues</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "video platform: ${option.video_service}"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>4be0ef08-889a-4366-ba29-0b0302fb5391</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVSLO.jpg) how the job looks and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WauwH.jpg) the result.

Comment: Great and simple stuff.